# Keycloak creating user for an existing realm?

Tags: java, keycloak, http-status-code-401, keycloak-services

I'm trying to create a user for an existing realm and client. Below, is what i tried. The URL, realm, username, password, clientId and clientSecret is correct. But it throws `NotAuthorization` exception on line `var response = keycloak.realm( realm ).users().create( user );` I also tried to get it with authorization toke but it threw the same error. What am i doing wrong?

```java
        Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance( serverUrl, realm, username, password, clientId, clientSecret );

        var user = new UserRepresentation();
        user.setEnabled( true );
        user.setUsername( "test" );
        user.setAttributes(Collections.singletonMap("origin", Collections.singletonList( "demo" ) ));

        CredentialRepresentation credentialRepresentation = new CredentialRepresentation();
        credentialRepresentation.setTemporary( false );
        credentialRepresentation.setType( CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD );
        credentialRepresentation.setValue( "1234" );
        user.setCredentials( Collections.singletonList( credentialRepresentation ) );

        try {
            var response = keycloak.realm( realm ).users().create( user );
            System.out.println( "Response: " + response.getStatus() );
            System.out.println( "Response: " + response.getMetadata() );

        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The error stack trace:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:603)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:149)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.heist.keycloak.user.generator.KeycloakGen.main(KeycloakGen.java:27)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.grantToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:90)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:70)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:65)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:590)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Related dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: 401 indicates a problem with username/password. Double check them and make sure user is from used realm and not from master realm.

Comment: No man. I checked it. Might it because Keycloak is running on my k8s cluster?

Comment: There can be a million reasons. So what Keycloak logs is saying about 401? I bet it's authentication or authorization error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently it seems it doesn't accept my login user `admin` as an authenticated user. So i added a new user and gave it the right roles as admin as below:[image]

[image]

After doing those, i was able to add users.